# React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.?

Tags: reactjs

I have a DupRoute component that creates an array of Routes, when I add a DupRoute component to the Switch I get an Error,
React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.
Here is my cat. https://codesandbox.io/s/74548ypmk6

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue says, somewhere in your code, you are having multiple components as children when it only accepts 1.

If I am not wrong, Route component inside of duproute.js doesn't accept multiple components. 
You have `{" "}
 {text}{" "}` inside of Route which I think is invalid.

Try changing

```
{" "}
{text}
{" "}
```

to

```
<Fragment>
     {" "}
     {text}
     {" "}
</Fragment>
```

Fragment can be safely used as it doesn't add any extra HTML element in our DOM.

Route component's responsibility is to render UI (that we give as part of props to it) when a location matches the route’s path.

Comment: how could I not notice it here and the result of copying and pasting,Thank you

Comment: Glad that it helped.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see route is a complaint about to have multiple children to render it, So you need to use `React Fragment` to combine those multiple children like

```
 <Route
          key={id}
          component={component}
          render={render}
          children={children}
          path={path}
          exact={exact}
          strict={strict}
          location={location}
          sensitive={sensitive}
        >
         <>
          {" "}
          {text}{" "}
          </>
        </Route>
```